# cron job set up for odd and even days triggers every day

Tags: cron

I want to run a different backup script every even and odd day.  So I set up cron like this:

```
0 4 */2 * * /bin/bash /root/backup-even-days.sh
0 4 1-31/2 * * /bin/bash /root/backup-odd-days.sh
```

However, the scripts both run every day.  Why?

Comment: Are you sure they run every day, or do they run on the same day but alternate days? `*` = first-last, so `*` in day-of-month is `1-31`, so you have the same setting for both scripts.

Comment: Shouldn't you specify day parameter in the first line as `2-30/2`? I think `*/2` means: run on every odd day. This is even one of the examples at the end of `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: You are both correct - see my answer and link below.

Comment: Yes, you're right, they actually both ran on the same day, every odd day.  I have fixed the error.  Quite clear in hindsight.

Answer (score 3):

The cron statement for each script execute on the same days - `*/2` evaluates to `1-31/2`.

See my [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602216/when-will-an-interval-cron-execute-the-first-time-ex-3-days/602222#602222) for more details.

To get alternating days, you could use `2-31/2` for the first script - this would start at `2` and skip every other for 2,4,6 etc.

Comment: I actually checked that with crontab-generator.org (and a number or other cron generators) and they all say it's correct, which it clearly is not... :-(   
Thanks, I'll fix it.

Comment: I use crontab.guru, and it clearly states that */2 will execute on odd dates.

Answer (score 0):

@Artur, thanks, works for me with even/odd hour and different minutes:
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (jammy, headless "server" installation)

```
$ crontab -e
(...)
1,11,22,33,44,55  0-23/2  * * *  /home/me/test1.sh >> /home/me/test.log
6,17,28,39,50     1-23/2  * * *  /home/me/test1.sh >> /home/me/test.log
# must have comment or blank last line
```

Running for example at 08:55, and next at 09:06
(my goal was to run about every 11min - which is 11x times within 2 hrs)

`<starting>{-<range-end>}/<every-nth>` with 0/11 for minutes works, but with different result ("every-nth" = modulo, check reminder zero?),
so will start at minute 0,11,22,33,44,55, and again 0 of next hour

---

(pls excuse the *answer* - but still cannot *comment* - IMHO: "nice" feature ;-/ )